# Comparing MySQL varchar and IBM DB2 varchar dataype

Tags: mysql, db2, varchar

I've a small doubt about MySQL `varchar` data type. As we all know.

`char` is a fixed-length data type. So, the storage size of the char value is equal to the 
maximum size for the column. But, in case of "varchar" it is a variable-length data type, 
so, the storage size of the `varchar` value is the actual length of the data entered, not the maximum size for this column. That's why, `varchar` generally more used when it need to store character/text kind of data and preserve un-used memory for future use.

Recently, I got to know that... in case of IBM DB2 if you use any `varchar` column in middle of rest of the columns of table then, the storage size of characters in that particular column is equal to the orignal size of the `varchar` column.

EX: if in a table there 3 columns like this:

1. firstName   : char(50)
2. lastName    : varchar(50)
3. emailId : char(50)

So, now if you want to store this text( 'Majhi' ) in to the coloumn "lastName" which of datatype `varchar(50)` then it'll take full 50char storage size rather than taking only 5chars which is the actual size of the actuall text( 'Majhi' ).

That's why, in IBM DB2 including of any varchar data type coloumn in middle of rest of coloumns of table whill also works same as `char` datatype works. So, memory optimization doesn't happen.

So, i just want to know is our MySQL works in same way or it dosen't differentiate where ever that `varchar` dataype coloumn exist and work accordingly as `varchar` datatype column need to work.

Comment: Your assertion that DB2 would store 'Mahji' using 50 characters in a varchar(50) if that field sits in the middle of a row is not correct.  It will take 9 bytes - 5 for the actual value, and 4 bytes to store the length of the string.  If the column is nullable, there will be 1 more byte for the null indicator.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects here.

First one is the on-disk storage. In this case for each row only as much data as needed is stored and it's not important if there are any other columns after varchar or not.

Second one is the table loaded into memory. In this case MySQL internally converts `VARCHAR(n)` to `CHAR(m)`[1] where `m` is the maximum length of data in given column. So if your column is declared `VARCHAR(60)`, but the longest string stored in it has a length of `10`, then the in-memory field will have a fixed length of `10`. This results in a compromise between minimizing the memory footprint and maximizing the performance of data access (it's easier to fetch specific column if you know where it starts).

[1]: Kind of simplification here. It's not really a `CHAR` or any other MySQL datatype.

Comment: An additional consideration is Unicode. The number of bytes may be more than the number of characters in both storage and disk.